Canonical bundle and formal completion
Are there simple examples of smooth subvarieties $Y$ of a smooth projective variety $X$ (over, say, the complex numbers) whose canonical bundle $K_Y$ does not lift to the formal completion $\hat X$ of $X$ along $Y$?
(equivalently, such that $det(N_{Y/X})$ does not lift to $\hat X$).

The is a duality for formal schemes that incorporates an analog of the canonical bundle. Perhaps this is not what you need.

There are effective Lefschetz theorems in SGA 2 that show a formal lift of an invertible sheaf to the formal completion often algebraizes to an invertible sheaf on a Zariski open containing $Y$.  Thus, for $Y$ a cubic scroll in $X:=\mathbb{P}^4$, the canonical bundle should not lift to the formal completion.

Thank you for your suggestion. But I do not see why a cubic scroll should satisfy the effective Lefschetz property.
